# js how to use dynamic ID from php array in js script

Tags: javascript, php

I search directories and I have folder names (about 30). I display them as links, but I would like to have a folder icon in front of each folder name. When I click on folder A, for example, icon1 should change to icon2. When I click on folder A again, icon2 should return to icon1. During this time, the icons of other folders do not change (after one click always I have: 1 icon2 and 29 icon1). For example, when the icon next to the folder A is icon2 and I click on folder B, the icon next to folder A will change (come back) to icon1 and the icon next to folder B will change from icon1 to icon2. The icon and its folder are a one button together.

My script is working with static ID (id="myB") of link but with dynamic (from array - $file) not. I tried to use a variable from php to enter the value in js but everything blocked.

test for Roy:

```
<body>
    <script>
    // JavaScript code
    const links = document.querySelectorAll('.myB');
    
    const clickHandler = e => {
      const img = e.target.querySelector('img');
      const link = e.target.closest('a');
      
      // close open folders
      closeOpenFolders(link);
    
      if (link.classList.contains('open')) {
        img.src = "folder.png";
        link.classList.remove('open');
      } else {
        img.src = "folder_open.png";
        link.classList.add('open');
      }
    }
    
    const closeOpenFolders = exclude => {
      links.forEach(link => {
        if (link === exclude)
          return;
          
        link.querySelector('img').src = "folder.png";
        link.classList.remove('open');
      });
    } 
    
    links.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", clickHandler));
    
    </script>
    
<?


    foreach ($file_info_all as $file){
    
    echo '<A href="test.php" target="main" class="myB"><img src="folder.png">'.$file.'</a><BR>';
       
        }   
    
    ?>

</body>
```

Comment: IDs must be unique, you can't use the same `id="myB" and `id="myImg"` each time through the loop.

Comment: yes, the link id="myB" (in static version) must be like id="'.$file.'" (in dynamic version. But , of course, I did not think about image id :((((((((((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't repeat the same `id` for multiple elements. A better approach would be to use a common `class` on those elements instead. You can then relate them by their hierarchy in the DOM when the event occurs, something like this:

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll('.myB');

const clickHandler = e => {
  const img = e.target.querySelector('img');
  const link = e.target.closest('a');
  
  // close open folders
  closeOpenFolders(link);

  if (link.classList.contains('open')) {
    img.src = "https://i.imgur.com/Zsc7Ylj.png";
    link.classList.remove('open');
  } else {
    img.src = "https://i.imgur.com/0JM7Yty.png";
    link.classList.add('open');
  }
}

const closeOpenFolders = exclude => {
  links.forEach(link => {
    if (link === exclude)
      return;
      
    link.querySelector('img').src = "https://i.imgur.com/Zsc7Ylj.png";
    link.classList.remove('open');
  });
} 

links.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", clickHandler));
```

```css
img {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<a href="test.php" target="main" class="myB">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Zsc7Ylj.png"> folder name
</a><br />
<a href="test.php" target="main" class="myB">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Zsc7Ylj.png"> folder name
</a><br />
<a href="test.php" target="main" class="myB">
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Zsc7Ylj.png"> folder name
</a><br />
```

Also note that I amended the logic to use a class to maintain state on the open/closed folder images which is slightly more robust as it removes the dependency on the folder image filename.

Comment: Thank you very much for your tip. I introduced it and here are the results: 1) it works (opens and closes) only every second link. 2) you can open the first link and the third one. Both can be open at the same time. And it should be - opening the third link automatically closes the first one.

Comment: In that case you need a little more logic to close all other folders and check the state of the one you're toggling. See my edited answer.

Comment: In your static version is ok but in dynamic is the problem as above. I used this code from your answer. In what point did you edit it?

Comment: Sorry, no one is working (i have 4 dynamic links)...

Comment: Rory, at the end part of my question is your code - maybe i do something wrong :((

Comment: Have you updated your PHP code to output the `myB` as a class instead of an id?

Comment: yes, of course. As I wrote above, at the very end of my query I pasted the current (your) and my code. The variables in the array are the letters of the alphabet A-Z.

Comment: Try checking the console for errors when you raise a click event handler

Comment: @Roy McCrossan - 3x Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'links' has already been declared. JS script for first $file is without error, but for 2,3,4 are with.

Comment: Ah I see - the problem is because you've put the script inside your PHP loop so it gets repeated for every `<a>` element you generate. Don't do that. Just put this script in your page once, outside of the loop. It will work for all elements.

Comment: @Roy McCrossan - inside <head> -> not working, inside <body> -> not working. You have all un-top, maybe copy to your file directory and test? please :))

Comment: The test version is in the snippet which clearly works absolutely fine. The issue must lie in how you're configuring the script on your side. Unfortunately, I can't really help with that

Comment: @roy McCrossan I pasted my complete code + yours in my query above. If you could test in any of your directory...

Comment: @Roy McCrossan I can't handle it. I copied your code onto a blank card, just him. No PHP. Doesn't work. Why does it work here and not on a blank card? maybe I need to load some JS source?

Comment: I can only assume you've not structured the page correctly. This is what the entire HTML output should look like: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/pdsL9agq/. Past this there's nothing I can do to help you with the information given in the question. If you're still struggling I would suggest you start a new question

Comment: @Roy McCrossan I want to thank you for your help and patience. The problem was that the js code had to be placed at the very end of the file. Now everything works fine. Thank you again.

Comment: No problem, glad we got there in the end :)